# firedac not available in rad studio

Tags: delphi, rad, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i have downloaded the rad studio from the following link:
https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/start-for-free

now my problem is that i want to set up a mysql connection via firedac, tutorials say that i must use the TFDConnection component, but i cannot find that in my tool pallet. i think my studio version does not support firedac.

how do i get firedac available in my rad studio?

Comment: You can't. Only in the higher editions.

Comment: i fixed it, they already send me an email with a key (forgot to look for that), had to reinstall rad studio and supply key while installing. now it works (for a limmited trial time).

Comment: Yes, for a limited trial period, you have (a slightly limited) Architect version, which has all the features (except, for instance, the source code to all the units). But after that, if you want to use Starter (the free one), you won't have it and can't install it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firedac is only available in the Architect, Enterprise and Professional versions

https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf

See page 17

Comment: I was afraid of that, but is was not sure. but now i am.

Comment: Note that : 
FireDAC Client/Server pack in Professional editions is OPTIONAL.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this could help some people, i had a similar problem : no fireDAC available, even after activating architect trial licence.

The problem was i had 2 coexisting RAD studio versions : i installed RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo starter and then RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Architect Trial. 
Though there were 2 distinct licences, it seems the 10.1 only accessed the tools supplied with the starter edition.

Uninstalling both and reinstalling only 10.1 Architect Trial solved the problem.